# Why my rxjs Subject subscription is called twice but not under debugger

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I have a basic subscription on a Subject like this:

```
this.service.webSocketDataEvents.subscribe(data => {
  this.handleDataStream(data);
});
```

The `webSocketDataEvents` is a `Subject<string>` that is fed by information from a backend like this:

```
public  webSocketDataEvents = new Subject<string>();

...

private messageHandler(message: MessageEvent) {
  this.webSocketDataEvents.next(message.data);
}
...
```

When I trace the backend I see exactly **one emission of a message**.

But my subscription is fired twice (with the same incoming message).

To make things even odder, I see only one firing of my subscription when I am under Chrome debugger.

This is baffling and impossible to debug (at least with a debugger).

Any idea, hint, suggestion ?

Thanks.

Comment: It's impossible to give you any advice based on this. I guess you're calling `this.handleDataStream(data);` twice somewhere

Comment: @martin: If it was the case, I would expect to have the debugger, firstly to trigger twice, secondly to show me a different stack trace. Following your idea, I have added a console.warn() call : it showed the exact same stack trace from the web socket call to my code. Then I have set a breakpoint next to the console.warn(); this removed the second call but I now have a weird message in blue  saying : '[Violation] '' handler took 235ms' for each "second missing" call. (!) It is getting murkier

Comment: @martin: Given the weird behaviour of my code, I am not expecting someone to magically understand the problem. Rather, I would like to gather return of experience in similar situation as I suspect there something happening behind the scene. Furthermore, having remarks like yours is very productive as it helps me refine my analysis. Thank you. :D

Comment: Can you make a demo that reproduces this problem?

Comment: I am not sure: it is a bit tricky because it involves a backend server and my code is not easily removable from its context. But if I cannot solve this another way, I'll try to do it.